# How much memory do I need to have for 100 million records

Tags: memory-management, byte

How much memory do i need to load 100 million records in to memory. Suppose each record needs 7 bytes. Here is my calculation

```
each record = <int> <short> <byte>
4  +  2  + 1 = 7 bytes
```

`needed memory in GB = 7 * 100 * 1,000,000 / 1000,000,000 = 0.7 GB`

Do you see any problem with this calculation?

Comment: If your record is represented as a structure (you don't really specify what language/platform is it), it might get padded to 8 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 100,000,000 records, you need to allow for overhead. Exactly what and how much overhead you'll have will depend on the language.

In C/C++, for example, fields in a structure or class are aligned onto specific boundaries. Details may vary depending on the compiler, but in general int's must begin at an address that is a multiple of 4, short's at a multiple of 2, char's can begin anywhere.

So assuming that your 4+2+1 means an int, a short, and a char, then if you arrange them in that order, the structure will take 7 bytes, but at the very minimum the next instance of the structure must begin at a 4-byte boundary, so you'll have 1 pad byte in the middle. I think, in fact, most C compilers require structs as a whole to begin at an 8-byte boundary, though in this case that doesn't matter.

Every time you allocate memory there's some overhead for allocation block. The compiler has to be able to keep track of how much memory was allocated and sometimes where the next block is. If you allocate 100,000,000 records as one big "new" or "malloc", then this overhead should be trivial. But if you allocate each one individually, then each record will have the overhead. Exactly how much that is depends on the compiler, but, let's see, one system I used I think it was 8 bytes per allocation. If that's the case, then here you'd need 16 bytes for each record: 8 bytes for block header, 7 for data, 1 for pad. So it could easily take double what you expect.

Other languages will have different overhead. The easiest thing to do is probably to find out empirically: Look up what the system call is to find out how much memory you're using, then check this value, allocate a million instances, check it again and see the difference.

Comment: Alignment is not enforced. However, non-aligned operands are  usually costlier to read.

Comment: If memory is at premium, you can allocate byte array and then assemble them back to ints with byte shifts.
Or just instruct the compiler not to align. +1 for you effort, though.

Comment: @RokKralj As the question does not specify a language, much less a specific compiler, I don't think you can say anything about what compiler options might be available. I used C/C++ as an example, not with the intent that these were the definitive numbers. The idea of packing things into a byte array to beat alignment rules would likely work in almost any language, though. Interesting thought.

Comment: I have been thinking of this problem more. If you have a 4,2,1 structure, you don't have to sacrifice that one byte per structure. You can allocate it groups of 4, like this (4,2,1),(1,4,2),(2,4,1),(1,2,4) and then repeat. No single byte gets wasted.

Comment: I'd have to be really desperate for memory space to want to implement something like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need just 7 bytes per structure, then you are *almost* right.

For memory measurements, we usually use the factor of 1024, so you would need

```
700 000 000 / 1024³ = 667,57 MiB = 0,652 GiB
```

Comment: You commented just while I was editing my answer :) You are right.

Comment: If I use Java or C++ will this memory requirement change? Will there be an advantage of one over the other?

Comment: In C++ you can store an array contigously with no extra overhead. In java, I guess the length of array is mandatory overhead, but that is just about 4 bytes.
It all depends how you implement it.