# Java Out of memory 2D Array

Tags: java, memory-management, arrays, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a 2D array as below.

```
int NUM_RECORDS = 100480507;

byte[][] completeArray = new byte[NUM_RECORDS][6];
```

Shouldn't it be enough to have `100480507 * 6 ~= 0.6 GB`

See [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614689/how-much-memory-do-i-need-to-have-for-100-million-records) question as well.

But creation of this array runs out of memory. I have allocated 4G to my java process through JVM args.

How can that be explained? I am I missing some thing trivial here?

This is my program

```
public class MemTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int NUM_RECORDS = 100480507;
       byte[][] completeArray = new byte[NUM_RECORDS][6];
       System.out.println("Array created");
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your program contain only this byte array allocation code, or something else?

Comment: You expect this memory to be allocated in stack?

Comment: it is a local method variable.

Comment: @Keyser I thought only the reference to the array is stored on the stack and the actual array is stored on the heap.

Comment: empirically, this assignment takes 4.5 GB of memory for me, not sure wether or not that's useful =).

Comment: You have allocated 4G of space, but it is segmented heap, and you can't just make a huge array and be sure that that's it. Arrays are specific that in his case your array needs 0.6G of continuous space, which is hard. Try with some dynamic structure, [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) for example. It is not true that array is on stack, just its reference, real data are on heap.

Comment: @AlvinWong Normally yes, but sometimes the compiler performs escape analysis and if it can prove that the object's reference cannot leave the method, it may choose to allocate the object on the stack instead. I seriously hope this is not the case here. It's more likely that the allocator can't find continuous space on the heap.

Comment: @partlov I tried using a linked list. program kept running until memory reached ~7GB and then crashed. what I am trying to do is insert a byte array of size 6.`byte[] contents = new byte[7]; ` in side a for loop  I am doing `completeArray.add(contents);`

Answer (score 2):

Each array has an overhead (for example, see IBM documentation on their overhead -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html). In your case, you are creating 100480507 of them!

If you change your code to "**byte[]** completeArray = new byte[**NUM_RECORDS*6**];", according to your theory, it should demand the same space! But, I am fairly certain this will work as there is least overhead. You could also try "byte[][] completeArray = new **byte[6][NUM_RECORDS]**;" and that should work too (lesser overhead).

I know this will not solve your issue - but I hope this will give you some perspective on the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I check the object layout in Harmony JVM (Other implementations of JVM are similar I suppose). Each Object in java has a object header that contains important information for JVM. The most important is a reference to the object's class (**one word**). Moreover, there are some flags used by the GC and to manage synchronization, i.e., lockword (since every object can be synchronized on) which takes up another **one word** (using partial words would be bad for performance). So that's 2 words, which is 8 bytes on 32 bit systems, and 16 bytes on 64 bit. Arrays additionally need an int field for the array length, which is another **4 bytes**, possibly **8 bytes** on 64 bit systems. So for each array, we have 12 additional bytes on 32-bit machine, and may be 24 bytes on 64-bit machine.

In your program, you have 6 arrays of array. 100480507 1D array. So the additional memory consumption is about 1.2 + 0.6 GB, which is a very large block of continous memory. The overhead is about 200%.

When we change the code to:

```
public class MemTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int NUM_RECORDS = 100480507;
       byte[] completeArray = new byte[NUM_RECORDS * 6];
       System.out.println("Array created");
   }
}
```

We only create 1 array, so the overhead is very small. About 0.6GB in total.

When the code changed to :

```
public class MemTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int NUM_RECORDS = 100480507;
       byte[][] completeArray = new byte[NUM_RECORDS][6];
       System.out.println("Array created");
   }
}
```

We got 7 arrays in total. The program will end immediately.

Create another 0.6GB memory in your code style, but change the element type from int to long:

```
public class MemTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int NUM_RECORDS = 12560063;
       long[][] completeArray = new long[NUM_RECORDS][6];
       System.out.println("Array created");
   }
}
```

The program can also end immediately. The overhead is about 150M/600M = 25%.

Comment: I did that. I saw a change in memory increase, it was not gradual increase. It gave `OutofMemoryError` after a while. My question is why the program is taking that much of memory. Why not just ~0.6GB? Further, all elements of the matrix are occupied.

Comment: What have done after create that 2D array? Is there any other big memory consumption in your program? Have you create some extra data structure to copy the element in that array?

Comment: I am not clear how  the overhead would decrease long[][] is used? In your second code example did you meant to interchange the indexes ( i.e `new byte[6][NUM_RECORDS];`)

Comment: Number of records decrease to 12.5M.