# Can't store large 2d array. Out of Memory error

Tags: java, heap-memory

I'm trying to create a large graph using a 2d array of longs, using data that is read in from a file. The number of nodes is 1000000, and the number of edges is 7586063.0. The code breaks at the creation of the 2d array.

This is for a graph that has to run Dijkstra & FloydWarshell. The graph is directed
I've tried keeping it as an array of Strings and not reading in the whole file at once.

```java
Graph( String filename) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String sr;
        sr=br.readLine();
        size = Integer.parseInt(sr);
        sr=br.readLine();
        numOfEdges = Integer.parseInt(sr);
        System.out.println("Size = " + size + ". Number of edges " + numOfEdges);
        edges = new long[size][size]; // breaks here
        String[] tester;
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfEdges; i++) { // currect node
            tester = br.readLine().split(" ");
            tester = reparse(tester);
            for(int j =0; j < size; j++) { //j = currect line of lines.
                if(j == Integer.parseInt(tester[0])) { // if start at i
                    edges[j][Integer.parseInt(tester[1])] = Long.parseLong(tester[2]); // [i][end] = 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to increase the heap for the JRE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Out of memory 2D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641794/java-out-of-memory-2d-array)